# HTML5 cross-window drag and drop 'dragend' event firing in wrong window

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've implemented HTML5 drag and drop (not using JQuery) and it's working fine within one window.  When I open a second instance of the same window (same web app) and try dragging and dropping from one browser window to another, the dragend event fires in source window, not the target window.  And the image that I'm dragging ends up replacing the entire target window (browser location set to image src).  Here's how I set up the dragend handler:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
```

I also added listeners for mouseover, mouseenter, and mouseleave, and those are firing in the target window.  It's only the dragend that's firing in the source window.  The mouseEvent has the source and target set to the same.

When I drag and drop the same source to target within the same window, everything works properly.

How do I get the dragend event to fire in the target window?  I can put together a jsfiddle if that would help but I was hoping I'm missing something obvious?

Tested that this happens in multiple browsers.

Comment: I've never used these APIs, but: Seems like normal behavior to me. `dragstart`, `drag`, and `dragend` should occur on the source window. The event you receive on the destination window should be `drop`.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right.  I guess this is a case where dragend and drop work equally well within the same window, but not cross windows.  Thanks!